# Rails HABM articles and categories, can't get categories links to view associated articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im making a news website and created Articles and Categories models that have belongs_to_and_have_many association.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles

    validates :name, presence: true, length: { in: 2..20 }, uniqueness: true

  def to_s
    "#{name}"
  end
end


class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

I created joined table

```
create_table "articles_categories", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "article_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
  end
```

Now, I managed to display articles and belonging categories on index and show sites. I want to make category links leading to sites with articles associated with a single category (e.x. sport => all articles with that category). In categories-index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Categories</h1>

<div class="row">
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>

    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <h2><%= link_to category %></h2>

      <h3>Articles</h3>
        <% category.articles.each do |article| %>
          <%= link_to article.title, article %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The links appear on the site but they don't route to anything. How can I make those links route to appropriate site?

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end


  def show
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def edit
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Category added' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Category not added'}
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update(category_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

   def destroy

    @category.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
  private
    def category_params
      params.require(:category).permit(:name, :article_ids => [])
    end
end
```

Comment: The first thing to stand out a mile is your `to_s` method. It's no good to redefine the class method. Furthermore, it is absolutely unnecessary in your case, because: a) ruby's syntax `'#{variable}'` is already returns a value as an instance of a String class; b) I suspect that your `:name` attribute is already a string from the beginning. 
And could you explain the logic of your App and categories/articles interactions more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `link_to` helper requires at least two parameters, the content to display and the place to route to.

Your category link does not include the latter

```
<%= link_to category %>
```

Depending on where you want the link to go, try something like this

```
<%= link_to category.name, category %>
```

This will link to the `CategoriesController#show` action. In that action, if you want to show articles for the given category, you can include something like this in the controller

```
# CategoriesController
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @articles = @category.articles
end
```